# Read all rows and cell values dynamic table asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, rows

I found the tutorial to create a dynamic table and add rows:

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/29/faq-dynamically-adding-rows-in-asp-table-on-button-click.aspx

How can I read all rows in the table, and then the values ​​of the textbox in the cells? The values ​​are entered in a table in a database (SQL Server).
Can I continue to use C# and asp.net or do I have to use Javascript?

I hope someone will give me help.

This is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Dynamic Adding of Rows in ASP Table Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Add New Row" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
public partial class _Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //A global variable that will hold the current number of Rows
    //We set the values to 1 so that it will generate a default Row when the page loads
    private int numOfRows = 1;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Generate the Rows on Initial Load
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GenerateTable(numOfRows);
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["RowsCount"] != null)
        {
            numOfRows = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RowsCount"].ToString());
            GenerateTable(numOfRows);
        }
    }

    private void SetPreviousData(int rowsCount, int colsCount)
    {
        Table table = (Table)Page.FindControl("Table1");
        if (table != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
                {
                    //Extracting the Dynamic Controls from the Table
                    TextBox tb = (TextBox)table.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j);
                    //Use Request objects for getting the previous data of the dynamic textbox
                    tb.Text = Request.Form["TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateTable(int rowsCount)
    {

        //Creat the Table and Add it to the Page
        Table table = new Table();
        table.ID = "Table1";
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(table);

        //The number of Columns to be generated
        const int colsCount = 3;//You can changed the value of 3 based on you requirements

        // Now iterate through the table and add your controls

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();

                // Set a unique ID for each TextBox added
                tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                // Add the control to the TableCell
                cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }

            // And finally, add the TableRow to the Table
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        //Set Previous Data on PostBacks
        SetPreviousData(rowsCount, colsCount);

        //Sore the current Rows Count in ViewState
        rowsCount++;
        ViewState["RowsCount"] = rowsCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here, I have used similar approach before. I could help you. You need to specify textchanged event for each textbox and on client side using javascript you can get the id's of textbox and values changed and then save it on server side using hidden field to store them temporarily.

Comment: do you always return null in the code 
Table table = (Table)Page.FindControl("Table1"); 
set a break point and check

Answer (score 3):

Since you're creating the table dynamically, you can't reference it like controls that are statically embedded on the page. To get a reference to the Table object you'll need to find it in the Page's ControlCollection and cast it out, just like in the example:

```
Table table = (Table)Page.FindControl("Table1");
```

The Table class contains a [table row collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rowcontrolcollection.aspx) which you will then need to loop over. Each row in the row collection has a [collection of cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.cells.aspx), each of which will contain [child controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.aspx) (see: Controls property) which will be your textboxes.

Comment: in this example table is always return null

Comment: Is the table's Id "Table1" or have you given it a different id?

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you take look at `SetPreviousData` this function is trying to read previous textbox value but there is some thing wrong with it i have done following changes and it works fine
first of all the following code in `SetPreviousData`

```
 Table table = (Table)Page.FindControl("Table1");
```

is always returning NULL because this function is not a recursive function and your table may be inside a container in your page so add following function to your code

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id)
    {
        return root;
    }

    foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
    {
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
        if (t != null)
        {
            return t;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

and change the code

```
Table table = (Table)Page.FindControl("Table1");
```

to

```
Table table = FindControlRecursive(Page , "Table1") as Table;
```

in next step change the following code in `SetPreviousData`

```
tb.Text = Request.Form["TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j];
```

to

```
tb.Text = Request.Form[tb.UniqueID];
```

set break points and see the results if it's tough to you let me know to provide you a function which returns table data in a `datatable`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var StringToSend='';
       function fncTextChanged(newvalueadded) {
           if (StringToSend != '')
               StringToSend = StringToSend + ';' + newvalueadded;
           else
               StringToSend = newvalueadded;
           //alert(StringToSend); -- For Testing all values
           // now store the value of StringToSend into hidden field ---- HFTEXTVALUES to access it from server side.
         }

    </script>
     <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" onclick="SaveTextBoxValues_Click" Text="save" /> 
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Add New Row" /> 
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTextValues" runat="server" Visible="false" Value="" />
```

Server Side :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Generate the Rows on Initial Load
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GenerateTable(numOfRows);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["RowsCount"] != null)
    {
        numOfRows = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RowsCount"].ToString());
        GenerateTable(numOfRows);
    }
}
protected void SaveTextBoxValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string AllTextBoxValues = hfTextValues.Value;
    string[] EachTextBoxValue = AllTextBoxValues.Split('~');
    //here you would get all values, EachTextBoxValue[0] gives value of first textbox and so on.
}

private void GenerateTable(int rowsCount)
{

    //Creat the Table and Add it to the Page
    Table table = new Table();
    table.ID = "Table1";
    Page.Form.Controls.Add(table);

    //The number of Columns to be generated
    const int colsCount = 3;//You can changed the value of 3 based on you requirements

    // Now iterate through the table and add your controls

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
            // Set a unique ID for each TextBox added
            tb.ID = "tb" + i + j;
            hf.ID = "hf" + i + j;
            tb.Attributes.Add("onblur", "fncTextChanged(this.value);");
            // Add the control to the TableCell
            cell.Controls.Add(tb);
            // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }

        // And finally, add the TableRow to the Table
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

One more thing, if you wish to store the values and retrieve them later, the code would be modified accordingly.

Comment: Would you please provide some code about now store the value of StringToSend into hidden field ---- HFTEXTVALUES to access it from server side

Answer (score 0):

reference for a dynamic table doesn't work well , blame microsoft ,

I use this :

Save inside a session List[YourObjectData] and every time you get into Page_Load , fill it the table

here is solution for number 2 :

somewhere inside Default.aspx

```
<div class="specialTable">
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"  />
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillDynamicTable();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}

private void FillDynamicTable()
{
    Table1.Rows.Clear(); //  Count=0 but anyways

    if (Session["Table1"] == null) return;

    foreach (var data in Session["Table1"] as List<MyObject>)
    {
        AddRow(data);
    }
}

private void AddRow(MyObject data)
{
    var row = new TableRow { Height = 50 };
    var cell = new TableCell();
    var label = new Label { Text = data.something, Width = 150 };
    cell.Controls.Add(label);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    Table1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must bind your table again at the `Page_load` event.For example if you are binding the table at `View_Click` button event,you have to call this method in `Page_load` event as `View_Click(null,null)`.